# Is there a common pattern for storing many boolean flags other than adding a ton of columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a bunch of booleans I need to associate with user accounts. They need to be toggled true and false, though not particularly frequently - they're going to be read more often than they're written. Most commonly they'll just be set from False to True once, but that won't always be the case.

Right now I'm thinking of appending columns to the user table like this:

| UserID | other_user_cols | did_a | did_b | did_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | False | True | False |
| 2 | ... | False | False | False |
| 3 | ... | True | False | False |

The thing is, there's quite a lot of these boolean columns.

Let's say you needed to add like, 100 columns. Is this really still the best way to do it?

Assume:

- It's not going to be very sparse - most users will toggle most booleans at some point
- The booleans aren't logically related in a way that could naturally be better organized
- New ones may need to be added from time to time
- the flags are directly associated with each user and no other info is needed other than the single boolean value

I feel this must be a pretty common pattern, and yet this way of just jamming more boolean columns into my table seems rather messy. Is there a more typical way of doing it that's a bit cleaner? Or is this actually the best way?

I'm using Postgres for this.

Here are some alternatives I've considered:

- serialize into a json list of strings (= the column names). This sounds even messier than the original and also not ideal if I ever want to do any serious SQL operations on the data
- Use numbers and bitwise operations - not sure how well this is supported and similar concerns about ever needing to do operations/lookups on individual flags
- Have a separate table like:

| UserID | flag_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | did_a | False |
| 1 | did_b | False |
| 3 | did_a | True |

That seems most reasonable to me as an alternative but not sure if it's really worth the trouble or if there's a better way.

Comment: How many rows (users) do you expect?

Comment: What is the expected read pattern for this data? Is it "check a single "flag" for a single user"? Or "check all users where flag x = ..."? What is meaning of those flags for/to the application/end-user? What structure does the data have in the application that sets the flags? Are the flags manipulated individually or as a whole per user?

Comment: Closely related answer discussing `boolean`, `integer`, and `varbit` for the purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993552

Answer (score 16):

I recommend using `varbit`, mostly because it is space efficient. Sure, storage space is cheap, but you have to cache in RAM, which is not so cheap, and manipulating smaller rows performs much better.

It is also easy to manipulate:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, flags varbit);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, b'11010001000110100');
```

To get the value of the tenth flag:

```
SELECT get_bit(flags, 9) FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;

 get_bit 
═════════
       0
(1 row)
```

To change the tenth flag:

```
UPDATE mytable SET flags = set_bit(flags, 9, 1) WHERE id = 1;

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;

 id │       flags       
════╪═══════════════════
  1 │ 11010001010110100
(1 row)
```

To add a new bit at the end:

```
UPDATE mytable SET flags = flags || b'1' WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. It looks elegant, but it's a horrible pattern to actually use. You need to reference a data dictionary to determine which bit is which, it's nearly impossible to tell at a glance what is going on with the data, it usually can't be meaningfully indexed, adding columns is difficult, removing columns is *very* difficult, bitmask operations are easy to get the logic backwards (`flags & '1010' = flags` vs `flags & '1010' = '1010'`), etc.

Comment: @BaconBits Sure it is ugly, but not much uglier than an array and a JSON. But I can accept that opinions differ on that.

Answer (score 3):

There are four mode: column, composite_type, and array, json

Array is my favorite mode,
Because,

1. there is no column quantity limitation
2. plenty of agg functions
3. easy operate compare to json

Here is example of column, composite and array;

```
drop table if exists  t_manycolumns ;
drop table if exists t_composite ;
drop table if exists t_arry ;
drop type if exists type_bits;
create table t_manycolumns
(id int,
is_1 boolean,
is_2 boolean,
is_3 boolean,
is_4 boolean,
is_5 boolean,
is_6 boolean,
is_7 boolean,
is_8 boolean
);
create type type_bits as (
is_1 boolean,
is_2 boolean,
is_3 boolean,
is_4 boolean,
is_5 boolean,
is_6 boolean,
is_7 boolean,
is_8 boolean);

create table t_composite( 
id int,
is_bits type_bits
);

create table t_arry(
id int,
is_bits boolean[]
);


-- column
insert into t_manycolumns (id, is_1, is_2, is_3, is_4, is_5, is_6, is_7, is_8)
select id, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false from generate_series(1,100) id;
--composite type
insert into t_composite (id,is_bits)
select id, '(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)' from generate_series(1,100) id;

--array type
insert into t_arry (id,is_bits)
select id, array[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false] from generate_series(1,100) id;


-- demo show search bit true in array

update  t_arry 
set is_bits[1]=true, is_bits[4]=true 
where id in (1,3);

select id, is_bits 
from t_arry
where is_bits[1]=true and is_bits[4] =true
order by id
```

The two importants things are :

1. array type can by pass the column quantity limitation.
2. the performance need be further study. Array performance should be high but it is  bit of like you are programming instead of run sql on relation database.

Hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Despite this question being well answered, just wanted to give my two cents that I'm personally a fan of the third implementation you mentioned, and have used it successfully for similar reasons before, since no one else has spoken up on it yet.

Relational Database Management Systems, especially ones naturally of the rowstore kind, can work well following this pattern when having to support a large number or highly variable columns, as long as you structure your consuming code appropriately. This generic type of table allows for much flexibility, and can even be indexed easily, as needed.

Comment: I like this approach as well. It works well enough until you have to filter on multiple flags at once, which is rather cumbersome. Might not be an issue in the OP's specific scenario (one flag per user, as I understood) but is still worth mentioning as a serious enough drawback in general, to give the reader a balanced view on this approach.

Comment: Agreed that of the three that is the most "normal" form for an RDBMS. The one issue with it as written is that is relies on a flag column that is actually three states - Truthy, Falsy and non-existent row. @Polygorial's answer addresses this and to the point of the OP's question is very much a common (perhaps even canonical) pattern for this data.

Comment: @640KB Could you elaborate on how that *three states* is an issue though? (I'm sure in some use cases it can be, but don't have any off the top of my head since in my prior use cases it wasn't.)

Comment: For one, there are logically only two states (boolean), so design-wise that's already a mismatch. Second the application that's utilizing the data would need to be built to handle two cases for the same value (if Falsy or if null). Third if you wanted to toggle the flag you'd have to do multiple operations (1: check if row exists, 2: if not, do an insert, otherwise do an update). The alternative to that would be to need to always insert 100 or so default rows when a user is created and insert a corresponding row to each user when a new flag is added to ensure there's always a value.